# Tkinter managing frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I came across a road block on one of my programs. The following is my code. I created a tkinter window app, with multiple frames. I was able to properly, set them up, with frames inside frames. However, I am stuck on not knowing why adding a label widget is modifying the size of the frame. Suggestions would be appreciated.

In the following code, please see the difference between uncommenting the couple of label widgets.

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    print ('Beginning')

    app = tk.Tk()

    size_x = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    size_y = app.winfo_screenheight()

    app.title('Color Mixer')
    app.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (size_x, size_y))
    # This disables resizing windows.

    #app.configure(background = 'yellow')

    print ('Beginning')

    #Main containers
    top_frame = tk.Frame(app, bg = 'yellow', width=size_x, height=int(size_y/3),  padx = 3, pady=3)
    bottom_frame = tk.Frame(app, bg='green', width=size_x, height=int(2*size_y/3), padx=3, pady=3)
    # layout all of the main containers
    app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    app.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
    bottom_frame.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

    # create the widgets for the top frame

    model_label = tk.Label(top_frame, font = ('Times', str(int(size_x*0.014)), 'bold'), bg = 'yellow' , text='Pick a Color Model')
    model_label.grid(row=0, column = 0)
    v = tk.IntVar()
    tk.Radiobutton(top_frame,
                   text="RYB Color Space",
                   indicatoron=0,
                   padx=35,
                   font=('Times',str(int(size_x * 0.0075)), 'normal'),
                   variable=v,
                   value=1).grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Radiobutton(top_frame,
                   text="CMYK Color Space",
                   indicatoron=0,
                   padx=20,
                   font=('Times', str(int(size_x * 0.0075)), 'normal'),
                   variable=v,
                   value=2).grid(row=2, column=0)


    top_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    top_frame.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
    top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

 # Bottom Frame - Dividing into two frames.
    bottom_left = tk.Frame(bottom_frame, bg='blue', width=int(0.5*size_x), height=int(2/3*size_y), padx = 3, pady =3)
    bottom_right = tk.Frame(bottom_frame, bg='red', width=int(0.5*size_x), height=int(2/3*size_y), padx=3, pady=3)
    bottom_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    bottom_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

    # ryb_note = tk.Label(bottom_left, font=('Times', str(int(size_x * 0.005)), 'normal'), bg='red', text='NOTE')
    # ryb_note.grid(row=0, column=0)
    # ryb_red = tk.Label(bottom_left, font=('Times', str(int(size_x * 0.005)), 'normal'), bg='red', text='Red')
    # ryb_red.grid(row=1, column=0)

    bottom_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck on not knowing why adding a label widget is modifying the size of the frame

That is how `pack` and `grid` are designed to work. By design, frames and other widgets grow or shrink to fit their children. It's a fundamental aspect of tkinter.

It's rarely a good decision to try to force a frame to be a specific size. Instead, make the inner widgets the minimum size necessary, then use the options to `grid` or `pack` to lay everything out correctly, and let tkinter do all of the math to make everything fit.

If you want the blue and red sections to be equal width, there are better solutions than to calculate their width. For example, you can use the `uniform` option to cause the two columns to have an identical size.

```
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1, uniform="half")
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1, uniform="half")
```

Note: `"half"` has no special meaning. It can literally be anything you want. As long as both columns have the same value, they will have a uniform width with respect to each other.

Comment: Bryan - You mentioned about removal of width/ height entries in the frame widgets. A question on your aspect is, if I follow that, how can I make sure, that the whole app covers the full screen? All the widgets inside a frame are packed together. Not spaced out properly.

Comment: @JeshKundem When you use the `geometry` method, that forces the window to be the requested size just as if you had manually resized the window.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Bryan's answer, however if you are looking for a quick fix, you can also just remove this line:

```
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
```

This will make the blue and red frames the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the two frames from being affected by their contents by adding a couple of`grid_propagate()` method calls as shown below. Here's some [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190323172714id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-methods.html).

```
    ...
    # Bottom Frame - Dividing into two frames.
    bottom_left = tk.Frame(bottom_frame, bg='blue', width=int(0.5*size_x), height=int(2/3*size_y), padx = 3, pady =3)
    bottom_right = tk.Frame(bottom_frame, bg='red', width=int(0.5*size_x), height=int(2/3*size_y), padx=3, pady=3)
    bottom_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    bottom_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    bottom_left.grid_propagate(0)   # Added
    bottom_right.grid_propagate(0)  # Added
    ...
```